# Can't handle an exception in method called by AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, exception, asynchronous

I can't seem to handle an exception properly. This is my async method:

```
private class PostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        String response;
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            apply.setText("APPLYING...");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                SendHTTPData sendHTTPData = new SendHTTPData();
                response = sendHTTPData.sendData(params);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("someTag", "Caught exception after doinbackground");
                response = "ERROR!";
            }
                return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute()
        {
            apply.setText(response);
        }
}
```

Now, whenever the `sendData` method is called, it returns either an "ERROR" or "APPLIED" string but when the web page is down, the exceptions ConnectException and SQLite Exceptions are generated and then my button gets stuck at "APPLYING" state.

I want to set the button text as "ERROR" whenever there is an error in the `sendData` method.

Here is my sendHTTPData class just in case:

```
public class SendHTTPData {

    public String sendData(String...)
    {
        String POST_DATA = "switch=" + sw + ...
            try {
                URL update = new URL(Utils.WEB_URL+path+"?"+POST_DATA);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(update.openStream()));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {}
                in.close();
                Log.w("someTag", "DONE GET RESPONSE");
                if(inputLine=="1")
                    return "APPLIED";
                else
                    return "ERROR";
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("someTag", "ERROR BC OF EXCEPTION");
                return "ERROR";
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onPostExecute` is not correct so it's probably never getting called it should look like

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void param)
{
    apply.setText(response);
}
```

Ideally, you should just send your response to your onPostExecute since that's where you use it so everything should look like this

```
private class PostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            apply.setText("APPLYING...");
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String response;
            try {
                SendHTTPData sendHTTPData = new SendHTTPData();
                response = sendHTTPData.sendData(params);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("someTag", "Caught exception after doinbackground");
                response = "ERROR!";
            }
                return response;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response)
        {
            apply.setText(response);
        }
}
```

Comment: How are you using the doInBackground to return a string when it is of void return type? Also, the code doesn't work, I tried it.

Comment: you return a string by changing the values here `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` the last string is for the return type. You should probably read the documentation about AsyncTasks

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna go do that. By the way, that worked like a charm. Thanks tyczj